# What is difference between const { service } = option and const service = option (express js)

Tags: javascript

I have found code which contains **const { service }** and I have changed is to **const service**
now it's not working. So my questions what is the difference between **const { service } = option** and **const  service  = option**

---

correct code

```
// greet.js
const express = require('express');
module.exports = function (options = {}) 
{ 
    // Router factory
    const router = express.Router();
    // Get controller
    const { service } = options;
    router.get('/greet', (req, res, next) => 
    {
        res.end(
            service.createGreeting(req.query.name || 'Stranger')
        );
    });
    return router;
};
```

---

Throws error

```
// greet.js
const express = require('express');
module.exports = function (options = {}) 
{ 
    // Router factory
    const router = express.Router();
    // Get controller
    const service = options;                    // throwing error after changing this line
    router.get('/greet', (req, res, next) => 
    {
        res.end(
            service.createGreeting(req.query.name || 'Stranger')
        );
    });
    return router;
};
```

Error message:

TypeError: service.createGreeting is not a function
    at d:\node\ch3\example 3\greet.js:12:21
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (d:\node\ch3\example 3\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

---

main file

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');

const greetMiddleware = require('./greet.js');

class GreetingService 
{
    constructor(greeting = 'Hello') 
    {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    createGreeting(name) 
    {
        return `${this.greeting}, ${name}!`;
    }
}

express()
    .use('/api/v1/service1', greetMiddleware(
        {
            service: new GreetingService('Hello')
        }))
    .use('/api/v1/service2', greetMiddleware(
        {
            service: new GreetingService('Hi')
        }))
    .listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "destructuring".

Comment: `const { service } = option` is an object destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. It is equivalent to `const service = option.service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const { service } = option` is equal to `const service = option.service`

When you remove the `{}` you are removing the **destructuring assignment**.

Answer (score 1):

In the first part, you are destructuring and assigning `options.service` to the `service` variable.

In the second part you are assigning the `service` variable to equal the `options` parameter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment